# How do I remove nan in list when using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a column('`col_name`') in my dataframe(`df`), and it contains several 'NaN's. I'm trying to put all of the values in the column into a list. But then I realized that the NaN value is also included in the list as `nan`. Please see the code below:

```
sizes = list(df['col_name'])
```

The result is like this:

```
[235, 235, 250, 255, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

How do I get rid of all the `nan`s?

Comment: Use `sizes = list(df['col_name'].dropna())`

Comment: @jezrael Well, I get ```'method' object is not iterable``` error. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: hmmm, maybe `nan` are strings? How working `sizes = list(df.loc[df['col_name'].ne('nan'), 'col_name'])`

Comment: @jezrael Welll, I don't get any errors now, but I still get ```nan```s in the list. Maybe the ```list()``` could be the problem?

Comment: No, `list` is OK. What is `print ((df.loc[4, 'col)name']))`,  `print (type(df.loc[4, 'col)name']))` for test `nan` type ? It is `float?` string?

Comment: @jezrael It gives ```<class 'numpy.float64'>```. Hmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227368/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ryan-oh).